# How to set the default audio input for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, default, microphone

I wonder how I can to set my default audio capture device (microphone) through Delphi.

I'm trying to use the functions of mmsystem api, following my code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 DevOutCaps: TWaveOutCaps;
 DevInCaps: TWaveInCaps;
 n, i: Integer;
 s: String;
begin
n := waveInGetNumDevs;
for i := 0 to n-1 do
  begin
    waveInGetDevCaps(i, @DevInCaps, SizeOf(DevInCaps));
    s := PChar(@DevInCaps.szPname);
    ListBox1.Items.Add(s);
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Ndev : Integer;
 Adev : Integer;
begin
Ndev := AudioInDeviceNameToDeviceID(ListBox1.Items.Strings[ListBox1.ItemIndex]);
Adev := GetWaveInDevice;
ShowMessage( IntToStr(Adev) );
ShowMessage(ListBox1.Items.Strings[ListBox1.ItemIndex]);
ShowMessage( IntToStr(Ndev) );
if waveInMessage(HWAVEIN(WAVE_MAPPER), DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET, Adev, Ndev) = MMSYSERR_NOTSUPPORTED then
   begin
   MessageDlg('NOT SUPPORTED', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
   end;
```

Preferably no third party components. 
Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The WinMM API would seem to be the way to go, using the DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET message Apparently, it is supported although undocumented under Win32 :-

[WinMM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909789.aspx)

Comment: I thought the internet was the following: dev: = 1; waveInMessage (HWAVEIN (WAVE_MAPPER), DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET, dev, 0);,but does not work, what do you mean?

Comment: You haven't read the documentation correctly. The first parameter is the original device, the second is the new device. Also, applying arbitrary values to parameters (like 1), isn't a recipe for success. You need to enumerate the number of devices in the system and make sure the values you are passing are actually valid. Finally, always check the result of any API call and handle it accordingly. Always supply the result when posting about a problem. "Does not work" is of no use to anyone.

Comment: I apologize for the "not working" was just a misinterpretation, is returning the following function, "MMSYSERR_NOTSUPPORTED".

I'm using windows 7

Comment: I don't have a Windows 7 machine here to try it on, have you succeeded in getting any on the WinMM functions working? Try something very simple first. As I mentioned in my original answer they are supposed to be supported but undocumented. Also, have you corrected the parameter order as I pointed out earlier? It's difficult to know what's going wrong when you don't post any code samples.

Comment: Yes it has a number of things I did that worked starting this API, I edited the post with the code I'm trying to do

Comment: You're calling WaveOUTMessage which applies to output devices (not microphones). You need to use WaveINMessage.

Comment: Apologies again, just ahead of myself and putting my code in a test that was wrong, already packed in own topic, you are testing on your machine too?